# регулярное выражение майл

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-‌​]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$")
```

Объясните, что здесь делает каждый символ по очереди? Или напишите другое регулярное выражение для e-mail с объяснением..

Comment: стоит посмотреть [справку по регулярным выражениям в MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Как разберётесь, напишите ответ, пожалуйста. Всем тоже хотелось бы знать, что делает каждый символ.

Comment: Качаем [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) и наслаждаемся. Нечего на этом сайте флудить вопросами типа "а-чё-это-за-символ". Если регулярка для PCRE/Python/JS, пользуйтесь [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

> ^

начало строки

> [A-Za-z0-9]

одна латинская буква или цифра

> [_\.\-]?

знак подчеркивания, точка или минус ноль или более раз

> [a-zA-Z0-9]+

буква или цифра 1 или более раз

> ([_.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*

вся комбинация 0 или более раз

> @

собака

> ([A-Za-z0-9]+)

буква или цифра 1 или более раз

> (([.-‌​]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)

см. предыдущий пример

> .

точка

> ([A-Za-z]{2,})

латинская буква два или более раза

> $

конец строки

Comment: .Спасибо большое,а нет ли более короткое выражение?

Comment: @D.Ed, есть в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562760/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-grep#answer-562774

Comment: @D.Ed: У вас на самом деле **слишком** короткая и неправильная регулярка. Правильная есть [тут](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) (и это она ещё не учитывает интернационализацию).

Comment: _что здесь делает **каждый** символ по очереди_ - нет объяснения для символов: `[`,`A`,`-`,`Z`,`a`,`-`,`z`,`0`,`-`,`9`, `]`,`(`, `)`, `_`, \, `.`, \, `-`, `?`, `+`, `*`, `{`, `2`, `,`, `}`